# Convert Forecast Data into a Data Frame

Tags: r

I have my forecast data as follows and I would like to create a dataframe from this output

```
Fcast<-hw(pays, seasonal = "multiplicative",level=c(80,95), h = 12)



Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95

Jan 2018       82399311      81064000 83734623 80357129 84441494
Feb 2018       82240607      80906903 83574310 80200883 84280330
Mar 2018       87439677      86020230 88859124 85268820 89610534
Apr 2018       82121058       80786169 83455948 80079521 84162596
..  ...        ......        ......    ....      .....    .......
Nov 2018       84527743      83123530 85931956 82380184 86675302
Dec 2018       83393393      82000730 84786056 81263498 85523287
```

**I want to create a data frame as follows**

```
Year Month Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
 2018 Jan      82399311      81064000 83734623 80357129 84441494
 2018 Feb      82240607      80906903 83574310 80200883 84280330
2018  Mar      87439677      86020230 88859124 85268820 89610534
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible. Just do `dput(Fcast)`

Comment: `sw_sweep()` from `sweep` package may be handy in this case.

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr, the following worked for me. Thank you @Prem.

```
library(dplyr) 


Fcast_df <- Fcast %>% 
  sweep::sw_sweep(.) %>% 
  filter(key == "forecast") %>% 
  select(-key)
```